# Firebase Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "[object Object]"

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to update a record in database with a new value but I get the 
Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "[object Object]" error.

```
onPressAdd = async(keyPlants) => {
   if (this.state.newNote === '') {
      alert('Note is blank');
      return;
   }
   currentUser = await firebase.auth().currentUser

   firebase.database().ref(currentUser.uid).child('plantList').child(keyPlants).update({
     note: this.state.newNote
   });
 }
```

I tried creating new variable inside the function with `var keyPlantss = String(keyPlants)` and passing it to the database ref but the error was the same.

keyPlants is a value from database passed with navigation

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
const keyPlants = navigation.getParam('keyPlant');
```

This is how my database structure looks like:

```
{
  "Rv2qgEYdLyR5njO8LAALWpgwbeB2" : {
    "monday" : {
      "-LidETJkPbBEaaKTzr_k" : {
        "nameC" : "tapertip onion",
        "nameS" : "Allium acuminatum"
      }
    },
    "plantList" : {
      "-LicubjdvSIrA8Z7V4vW" : {
        "bloom" : "Summer",
        "drought" : "Medium",
        "fcolor" : "Purple",
        "gperiod" : "Spring and Summer",
        "lifespan" : "Short",
        "mheight" : 30.478512648582743,
        "moisture" : "Low",
        "nameC" : "tapertip onion",
        "namePlant" : "Allium acuminatum",
        "pcURL" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Alliumacuminatum.JPG",
        "toxicity" : "None"
      },
      "-Liy_JT1VyqiqmY82dLN" : {
        "bloom" : "",
        "drought" : "",
        "fcolor" : "",
        "gperiod" : "",
        "lifespan" : "",
        "mheight" : "",
        "moisture" : "",
        "nameC" : "",
        "namePlant" : "Tanacetum pilosum",
        "pcURL" : "",
        "toxicity" : ""
      }
    },
    "thursday" : {
      "-LiyEo6s5QgNj3rqura4" : {
        "nameC" : "tapertip onion",
        "nameS" : "Allium acuminatum"
      }
    },
    "tuesday" : {
      "-Liya4u6LnbJSbkAx9ji" : {
        "nameC" : "",
        "nameS" : "Tanacetum pilosum"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like `keyPlants` is an object and not a string. Casting it to a string with `String(keyPlants)` isn't going to produce a different result, you'll still just get `"[object Object]"`

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: I've exchanged the picture for the code like you suggested. Thank you